# Is adding multiple indexes on one table harmful for inserting?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have three statements on one table. Two `SELECT` queries and one `INSERT` query.

```
// first
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id_user = :id AND seen IS NULL

// second
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE id_user = :id AND timestamp > :tm

// third
INSERT INTO mytable (id, id_user, timestamp) VALUE (NULL, :id, :time)
```

AS you see, based on those two first `SELECT` queries, I need these two indexes:

```
ADD KEY id_user1 (id_user, seen);
ADD KEY id_user2 (id_user, timestamp);
```

All fine. But I heard indexes are harmful for `INSERT`, `UPDATE` statements. I mean an index makes `INSERT`, `UPDATE` slow. So I want to know, should I just  add an index on `id_user`, Something like this:

```
ADD KEY id_user (id_user);
```

Actually I'm trying to make a fast *selecting* and *inserting*. So what kind of indexes should I add based on those three statements?

Comment: Short answer:  There is less harm to `INSERT` in having another index than the benefit to `SELECT`.  (Usually.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *optimal* indexes for the two `select`s are the ones given.

However, either `select` can use either of the indexes.  You should test the performance on a reasonably sized set of data to determine if it meets your needs.  In all likelihood, one index will meet your needs.

Your `insert` will require inserting rows into whatever indexes are assigned, as well as the data tables.  This does increase the effort of the insert.  But, unless the peak volume of your inserts is at least in the hundreds per second, then you don't need to worry about about the performance.

Computers are pretty fast nowadays and databases are pretty well written.  Unless you have a lot of data and a lot of data being loaded, then the `insert` performance is probably not an issue.

Comment: You know, you helped me very much in these days, not just in this answer, I mean all your answers for my other questions. I just want to say *thanks*. I know, you often don't read your comments, but I hope you read this one.

Answer (score 2):

Well, that's a very general question, it is data dependent . An index can harm, can help but you can't always predict it before trying to run it. You can look at the execution plan before and after adding the index to decide better.

In general, index harm performances of `INSERT` statements, they usually help `UPDATE` statements and not harm them(again, depend on the index and on the update statement) .

To decide which indexes you need to add,you need to review what exactly will you do on this table on daily basis, if its mostly updates, then you should defiantly add the indexes on the columns of this update.

We can't supply an answer that will be correct for you, unless you ask a specific question including tables design and required mission, so if you have one, update your question and post it.

Comment: Thanks for writing an answer +1.  Actually your answer is an explanation just for the *title* of my question, just that. I mentioned multiple queries into my question and I need to know what kind of indexes is needed based on them.

Comment: As I said, it depends, is this a one time insert ? The indez will harm the performances of the index, but it depends on the size of the data, so I can't provide an answer without an execution plan.